# UIViewController's navigation bar backButton still shown despite leftBarButton set

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `UIViewController` presented in a `UINavigationController` stack that when presented, the left side of the navigation bar should only show a custom Button, not the back Button.

Desired outcome:
[image]

Current outcome:
[image]

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624946-leftbarbuttonitems) says that assigning items in the `leftBarButtonItems` array should hide automatically the back button, or when the `leftItemsSupplementBackButton` is set to false.

I tried many things:

```
let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(...)
navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([leftButton], animated: false)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = false
navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

None of these options work as intended.

Comment: can you say, when or where you call the above function?

Comment: are you presenting or pushing?

Comment: I tried either from `viewWillAppear()` or `viewDidLoad()`. Behaviour was the same, but I kept it in `viewDidLoad()`.
The view is pushed.

Comment: when you want to have a page out of the stack why don't you present it? the presented page does not depend on the navigation Stack.

Comment: I'm refactoring an existing workflow, I don't intend to change presentation style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized, later on, that the `UIViewController` is actually a subclass of `UIHostingViewController`. So the SwiftUI View was also managing the navigation bar. Setting `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden()` to the hosted `View` resolved my issue.